# Clipping/Removing overlapping polygon drainage areas?

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, overlapping-features, basin

I have used the upslope command to create multiple drainage areas. Area1 is the entire basin, Area2 is a little smaller and overlaps Area1, Area3 is a little smaller and overlaps Area2, this continues for all 12 areas. Is there a command that will divide Area 1 into smaller polygons?[image: All areas, need to break the yellow area, which is beneath all the other polygons, into smaller polygon segments]

Comment: Are you looking to use a QGIS equivalent of the Update tool in ArcGIS?

Comment: Yes sir, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wanting a tool for QGIS that is the same as the [Update tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/update.htm) in ArcGIS.

Unfortunately for you, there does not appear to be a similar tool in existence yet.

However, this [answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251772/qgis-looking-for-an-update-function-similar-to-arcgis) by [artwork21](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1608/artwork21) gives a good work flow for a multistep workaround. Hopefully you are able to complete your task by following the instructions in the answer.